# Django: transaction.atomic in CreateView, form_valid()

Tags: python, django

Does it make sense to have `transaction.atomic` for `form_valid` in my `CreateView`?

```
    @transaction.atomic
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.instance = form.save(commit=False)
        self.instance.event = self.request.event
        # When the super method is called the instance
        # is saved because it's a model form
        super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form has many-to-many fields, then the transaction decorator will ensure that the queries to save the instance and many-to-many fields run in the same transaction.

If your form doesn' have many-to-many fields, then there will be a single SQL query to save the row and a transaction isn't necessary.

As an aside, your return statement is duplicating what `super().form_valid(form)` would do. You could do `return super().form_valid(form)`, or it might be clearer to call `save()` explicitly.

```
@transaction.atomic
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.instance = form.save(commit=False)
    self.instance.event = self.request.event
    self.instance.save()
    self.instance.save_m2m()  # if you have m2m fields
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Perfect + you actually showed me a mistake I made in my code. I have m2m fields and didn't realize they are not saved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Having looked at the Django code, I think the `super().form_valid(form)` would have saved the m2m fields even after you called save with `commit=False`. But because that wasn't immediately obvious to me, I would prefer to call `save()` and `save_m2m()` explicitly.